# How to extract only the sentences matching word condition whilst preserving data frame

Tags: r

The code section underneath is a good representation of the dataset that I am dealing with.

```
x <- "test is bad. test1 is good. but test is better. Yet test1 is fake"
y <- "test1 is bad. test is good. but test1 is better. Yet test is fake"
a <- "this sentence is for trying purposes"
z <- data.frame(text = c(x,y,a))
z$date <- c("2011","2012","2015")
z$amount <- c(20000, 300, 5600)
z$text <- as.character(z$text)
```

What I want to do is essentially extract only the sentences containing the word test1 and parse them in a new column (z$sentences) to do other operations on.

I have tried using the following:

```
z$sentences <- grep("test1", unlist(strsplit(z$text, '(?<=\\.)\\s+', 
                              perl=TRUE)), value=TRUE)
```

But it returns an error because the replacement has 4 rows whilst the data has 3.

I have also tried with unlist but the other column information is sadly lost in the process.

2 results are satisfactory for this:

Extra column with only the sentences containing "test1" or long format with each row still containing the data (date, amount) with the sentences.

Expected output:

[image: With all sentences that match in column]

With all sentences that match in column

[image: with a new row for each sentence matching condition]

with a new row for each sentence matching the condition, although the last row does not have to be present.

Any help welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `grep` only returns the `match` elements which can be less than the original length

```
lst1 <- strsplit(z$text, '(?<=\\.)\\s+', perl = TRUE)
z$sentences <- sapply(lst1, function(x) paste(grep("test1", x, 
        value = TRUE), collapse=" "))
```

---

Another option without splitting would be `gsub`

```
trimws(gsub("(([A-Za-z, ]*)test1[A-Za-z, ]+\\.?)(*SKIP)(*F)|.",
             "", z$text, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "test1 is good. Yet test1 is fake"   "test1 is bad. but test1 is better."
#[3] ""
```

Comment: Is there any way around this? Using a different function or a combination of? I've searched but couldn't find a satisfactory solution yet.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `str_extract` from the `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)

z$sentences <- str_extract(z$text,'.*test1.*')

z
                                                               text date amount                                                         sentences
1 test is bad. test1 is good. but test is better. Yet test1 is fake 2011  20000 test is bad. test1 is good. but test is better. Yet test1 is fake
2 test1 is bad. test is good. but test1 is better. Yet test is fake 2012    300 test1 is bad. test is good. but test1 is better. Yet test is fake
3                              this sentence is for trying purposes 2015   5600                                                              <NA>
```